# Does Self-Moderation work?

Tags: discussion

According to [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/), one of the central tenants of Stack Exchange is that *the community at large* moderates itself.  By judicious use of upvotes, downvotes, and votes for closing, the community decides what is "good" and what is bad.

Does this work in practice here at politics?

Answer (score 7):

Yes and No. *Primarily No*; sadly.

Closing subjectivity-inducing / opinion-based questions we have had a spotty track record on; possibly getting better. But NPOV (or SE equivalent) answers and comment-chain restraint hasn't worked as well without active moderation I'm afraid. A draw back of being a soft science stack with a highly passionate membership.

The hands off approach won't make the site any worse than it already is; but with a lack of [entrainment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operant_conditioning_chamber) of the current membership, it isn't going to get any better either.

So I'm of the mind that laissez-faire has capped out for *Politics.se* and we need to have a condensed set of [clear](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legal_certainty), possibly arbitrarily ontological, rules defined in Meta and enforced through escalating and consistent punishments up to and including the timeout penalty box.

We'll lose only a few members and entrain the rest so effectively as to increase the overall quality of the site notably.

Comment: Any that you lose won't be the kind of people that can positively contribute anyway.

Comment: Of course, what constitutes a NPOV answer would be solely the purvue of those same left leaning members of the stack that currently upvote (with no single downvote) every POV answer that looks good to left wing and downvote factual asnwers without ability to state which of the facts are wrong, when said answers are negative towards left wing views. So basiclaly you'll turn it into "liberal_politics.SE", with no disagreements, thus reducing to prior meta question about splitting into 2 exchanges but with no exchange left for those whose politics was voted out. Elegant.

Comment: @DVK As far as I can tell we have a healthy mix of both common ideological camps. What we need are agreed upon and _enforced_ site etiquette and site standards. Nothing controversial for a stack exchange site. _Politics.se_ has backslid into a forum, or began as one. This stack doesn't have a special remit to be argumentative. If we want to improve the site we need to, like an alcoholic, admit we have a problem; and admit that this a _structural_ problem, not the fault of one side vs another.

Comment: @LateralFractal - I have given you numerous examples of content that was worth moderating out but had ZERO such moderation and positive votes. THOSE peolpe won't need to leave, and since you don't mind their content's implications, you don't see it as "not following basic level of behavior".

Comment: @DVK Sigh. I rather dislike culture warriors and their mindset. You are all up in arms that the purpose of increased moderation is a putsch to kickban specific ideologies. It is entirely pointless for me to tighten down on posts you suggested for three reasons: 1) I'm not a moderator and as I've said, self (i.e. community) moderation at this point isn't sufficient; 2) We need an agreed structural reform agenda in Meta before we begin; 3) You have been highly selective as to precisely what posts you point out need attention; as if I don't know the problem is _structural_. Do you know this?

Comment: @DVK What exactly are you trying to say? That you _like_ the quality of posts we have? That higher moderation of the site is all about me me me spy vs spy ideological cant? It's not personal, it's _not_ ideological, it's structural and we have to fix this regardless of children who are perfectly happy to SHOUT and kick and scream each day like this a sandbox forum for bad prior life experiences.

Comment: @LateralFractal - I'm trying to say that I will take the calls for improved quality a lot more seriously if they would NOT be coupled with a completely one-sided political application of what's considered "quality". As I noted repeatedly, I gave you plenty of examples where that's not happening. Until you specifically address that trend, no platitudes about caring about quality would convince me that quality is really the goal.

Comment: @DVK You are like someone who sees firemen come to their burning house and automatically assume they are thieves. Are you telling me _with a straight face_ that you can't conceive of quality problems with this site that are ideologically neutral? You are spiking the punch before we even begin, out of a completely irrational fear that my motives are not precisely what I've said they are. Besides, what ideological pre-conditions you demand before site improvement is irrelevant - since you've clearly never cared about raising the level of this site yourself; just enjoy wallowing in the mud.

Comment: Sigh. Between moderators that are too hands-off and members that _enjoy_ having this site as a political mud-wrestling pit between opposing clown cars - Any drive to raise this site to the standard of the rest of the network is doomed to failure. Again. And Again. Have fun with that writhing pit of hate in your heart, @DVK: You'll have it for the rest of your life.

Comment: @LateralFractal - sure I see quality problems with the site. I just don't see a genuine bias-free effort to clean them, so I'm not about to acknowledge the effort to clean them in a biased way. As I said, if you want to have left-wing-politics.se, you can have it and clean it up without my efforts. If you want to have a clean politics.se, don't act like the only low quality stuff on the site is right wing, which is exactly what you do now.

Comment: @LateralFractal - re: firemen... a closer (and interstingly enough) analogy to what I percieve is a cop who hangs out at the store and gets freebies and occasionally extorts bribes from the owner. You're welcome to tell me that doesn't happen.

Comment: @LateralFractal - what I enjoy is for the site to be **balanced**. I would prefer that it'd be a clean, high quality balance if I had my choice. But if there won't be balance on the clean side, I would rather have a POV balance than no balance at all because the latter will turn the site into a free propaganda tool for people whose ideology I oppose.

Comment: @LateralFractal - if you want to restrict the site to 100% only questions dealing with theory of voting and such, I'll join you on THAT crusade.

Comment: @LateralFractal Are there any rules that you have in mind?

Comment: @SamIam Best we do that in a fresh meta question. I'd have to dig through meta stack exchange blogs and articles on moderation to figure out what needs to be re-iterated; although that's probably over-researching what we already know. Consensus on common behaviour hopefully won't be controversial; but consensus on enforcement might be, if some fear they can't act up with impunity any more.

Comment: @LateralFractal The thing is, I don't know if you can really come up with any concrete rules that will both eliminate moderator bias and produce the level of moderation that people seem to want.

Comment: @LateralFractal the reason I think that, is because I suspect that some people want their own bias to be reflected in the moderation.

Comment: @SamIam It's a risk, I know. But better than doing nothing. The first month of increased moderation is probably the hardest, as the probability that posts requiring moderation will be perfectly symmetrical across classical biases is low. Much like getting exactly 25 tails in 50 coin flips. Confirmation bias of inferred moderation bias, so to speak. Collective belief in consistency is easier to prove if the rules and the circumstances of their application are clearly defined. Put simply, we need to put training-wheels back on the bike.

Comment: @LateralFractal - here's a fun example from you. A user posted a question with such an obviously wrong and biased statement as "a pure Right ideological element, such as a dictator". Lo and behold, another user did an extensive edit; and **left that statement intact** (never mind a less idiotic but still biased and wrong-on-many-levels "equal rights - Pure Left ideology")

Comment: @LateralFractal - another example of entirely biased wording that went unchallenged by left wing moderators until a right wing one had to bother: http://politics.stackexchange.com/posts/264/revisions

Comment: @DVK Sigh. You scrabble about looking for excuses not to support increased moderation. Firstly, the Tea Party [question](http://politics.stackexchange.com/posts/264/revisions) occurred before I arrived. Secondly, if you read the revision comment for that communism [question](http://politics.stackexchange.com/posts/6354/revisions), you will note that my revision was to clean up grammar and spelling; not because I agreed with the content, but because content edits should be negotiated with OPs. I closed-voted the question as opinion based and upvoted/agreed with your answer to said question.

Comment: @DVK The irreducible kernel of that [question](http://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/6354/has-the-world-ever-seen-pure-communism) was opinion-based and on that basis unsalvageable without OP feedback. Should I have bothered reducing some the eye-grating formatting of that question considering it was unsalvageable? Possibly not; but performing some clean-up, close-voting as opinion-based and waiting for OP feedback to change the kernel isn't unusual and I don't think should be inferred as supporting the question.

Comment: @DVK This attack (you) and defence (me) dialogue model you've created is simply because you prefer this; not because you have any moral high ground. Indeed not. Do you want me to switch to attack-style commentary and dig up all your biased posts? That task will be remarkably easy. So yeah, I suggest you stop side-stepping the original moderation discussion of this meta Q&A; with wild neverending accusation of other people's bias. You recognise that bias requires two people to exist right? And that "bias bias everywhere but not drop to drink" has to be partly in your own head.

Comment: @LateralFractal - I don't claim to have a moral high ground. I am explaining to you why your calls for "improved quality" come across as less genuine than they might very well be and thus not attractive to participate in. My MAIN goal is not letting this site to become imbalanced liberal propaganda tool. Whether that happens by fair and balanced moderation that excises liberal bias (including dealing with heavily upvoted biased crap); OR by introducing a balancing anti-liberal bias, is a secondary concern, unless, as mentioned, you rename the site into "liberal-politics.SE" -then bias is OK

Comment: @DVK Well, I obviously prefer the former over the latter as two POVs don't cancel out to become a NPOV site. If we've come to a consensus that the first option is something you can stomach (i.e. excising rhetorical tricks that promote bias); then we can proceed to the next step in separate meta question of articulating what tricks we prohibit and penalties for breaching them. Whether you believe my sponsoring this objective is something you can not be but cynical of is simply a concern that will resolve itself with time.

Comment: @LateralFractal  - My litmus test is simple - will you agree with my list of biased content that needs to be moderated, at least in large portion. And not only because YOU agree that it's biased, but because you legitimately recognize that your own internal biases cause you to be less sensitive to what's biased to the opposite side. IOW, the error on what's biased has to be on "at least someone agrees it's biased" and not "majority vote says it's biased" which is how we got to where we are today.

Comment: To reiterate - I'm quite willing to restrict the site to 100% questions of theoretical political science/voting theory. It's quite hard to make THOSE biased. AND might attract experts and not sure prosumers

Comment: @DVK I agree with every point you are making about hidden bias and majority bias risks; which is why I suggest we tackle the structural problems (symptoms) because we can't wave a wand and make people bias-free robots. I feel most of posts which are politically biased in the view of one camp or another also happen to be inadequate in non-political ways that fall under generic stack exchange moderation. My view is if we [entrain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operant_conditioning_chamber) enforcement of generic non-political quality and etiquette requirements, we'll move towards a better site.

Comment: @DVK, I resent being called "a right wing" [moderator?]. ;) joking aside, I rarely edit left-wing propaganda in questions because I find it more useful for future left-wing sympathizers to be able to find their biased questions. Hopefully they will read all the answers and see a well reasoned response rather than just the politically correct one (which usually has higher votes).

Comment: @user1873 - And that contributes to the "Right wing gets edited, left wing doesn't" view that DVK was mentioning.

Comment: @Bobson, your point being what? Liberals/progressives cannot tell when they are being biased, and need a conservative/libertarian to do it for them? ;) (I mean remove their bias, not be biased)

Comment: The problem, @dvk, is that your definition of 'balanced' isn't really everyone else's definition of 'balanced'. The fact that you have defended user1873's style of questions but are up-in-arms about the Tea Party question (which, for the life of me, I don't see what you find is biased in it) is *exactly* what you are complaining about, but flipped 180 degrees. (ie, you seem to feel the site is far-left and won't consider it balanced until it is far-right).

Comment: I'm getting too wordy. Anyways, my point is that 'balanced' doesn't mean giving equal weight to every viewpoint. The world is round. Some people still will argue it's flat, but we don't have to give that POV equal billing for the debate to be 'balanced'.

Comment: Finally, OMG THE IRONY of user1873 editing the 'controversial one line' in the Tea Party question but fighting tooth-and-nail when being called out on their novel-length out-of-context quoting. :)

Comment: @DA. - The fact that you equate one political viewpoint with the world being flat is the reason I fully disagree that this site can be moderated in a balanced way

Comment: @DVK What political viewpoint do I equate with the world being flat? Does it even matter? My point is that a fringe viewpoint doesn't need equal weight in a debate for it to be balanced. Do you disagree with that?

Comment: @DA. - given your extensive posting around here, it's pretty easy which of the 2 viewpoints you consider "fringe".

Comment: @dvk You're talking in insinuations. I can only assume you don't disagree and that your definition of 'balanced' is that all viewpoints must be given equal weight. If that's the case, then yea, this place will *never* be balanced by your definition. Which I don't think is a bad thing. We have cable news for that kind of 'balance'.

Comment: BTW, your extensive posting tends to use phrases like "idiot liberals" so I hope you see some of the irony in your argument here.

Comment: @DVK - This actually comes back to what I see as the fundamental question which determines whether this site *can* work.  **In your view:**  Does "Balanced" mean `"Every viewpoint is equal, regardless of facts or general acceptance"` or does "Balanced" mean `"Every viewpoint is as valid as the facts that support it"`?

Comment: @user1873, you're invited to answer this question too.

Comment: @DA. - And you, although I suspect we can guess your answer based on your previous comment.

Comment: @everyone - I'll provide my own answer in a few days.  Sorry for the multiple comments, but I wanted to notify everyone, and you can only do one person per comment.

Comment: @Bobson - originally I would tend to be on the "facts" option. After seeing posts with equal amounts of factual support getting wildly divergent voting based clearly on politics, I fail to see how it can possibly work at this point. (hell, even on Skeptics, politically correct answers with poor factual support garner tons of upvotes at times).

Comment: @Bobson we'd have to agree on 'facts' first. :) Which, to be fair, is perhaps why this is tough for a SE site. I actually don't mind anyone having a political viewpoint. It's *how* a lot of questions are posed here that I have problems with--not that they are right or left wing.

Comment: @Bobson, I guess the latter, but why are we arguing on the definition of 'balanced'? I guess my Obama question was very balanced since it had supporting facts for his can/cannot delay deportation.

Comment: @DVK - I'm just trying to make sure that we're coming from the same starting point, because after your response to DA's "flat earth" question I wasn't sure.  There *are* fringe political theories on both sides (as well as those that don't sit neatly on the spectrum) that have little or no basis in fact.  (For the record, I'm strongly on the "have facts" side.  Even if the meaning of the facts is debatable, there's at least something to debate.)

Comment: @DA. I have a pretty broad definition of facts. I'm not talking about just surveys, studies and the like. My definition more-or-less boils down to "Can this 'fact' be proven right or wrong? Or is it [unfalsifiable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falsifiability)?"  It's possible to prove that the Earth isn't flat.  It's possible to prove that people can fly using their minds alone (no one has done so, but if there ever is a documented case, that will prove it).  It's not possible to prove the [FSM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flying_Spaghetti_Monster) is invisibly moving my fingers to type this.

Comment: @user1873 - Individual questions don't need to present both sides, unless they're asking about the difference between those two sides.  Simply saying "Which of these two is right?" sets up a [false dichotomy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_dilemma), where it's possible that the "right" answer is a third side that didn't even get mentioned.   When I'm talking about balance, I'm talking about the site as a whole.  Individual questions are quite welcome to be heavily biased towards one side or the other, so long as they're still good SE-style questions.

Comment: I just found [this answer](http://meta.politics.stackexchange.com/a/1346/2130) from AffableGeek, which is a great writeup of my stance.

Comment: @Bobson - that's your personal opinion, sadly. The site consensus is that any questions that are biased to conservative site aren't welcome here as a rule, no matter how well they fit SE guidelines. Simply because they are posted - as people tend to put it - "in bad faith".

Comment: @DVK - That's what I'm trying to help change. I think any *good question* should be welcome here, regardless of whether I love it or think that the idea is the stupidest thing I've ever heard.  And I think it is possible to define a "good question" in a non-partisan manner.  I may be naïve or overly optimistic, but I do think it's possible.

Comment: @DVK I still get the impression that you feel votes are being handled based on ideology, rather than quality of the question. To be fair, I'm sure both are happening. But you seem to ignore the quality aspect entirely. "Bad faith" isn't an ideological issue--it's a quality of question issue. For example, most of user1873's questions that we have beefs with could easily be rewritten and still ask the same core question without the agenda. Because user1873 likes to write trollish questions at times does not mean the entire site is ideologically against you.

Comment: @Bobson and the 'fact' thing is certainly a sticky issue. You see a lot of questions posted where the OP attempts to get you to prove a cited fact in the question wrong assuming that because they cited a fact, their question is infallible. While ignoring (willfully or not) the issue is that their fact is out of context and/or they're attempting to create causality where it doesn't necessarily exist.

Comment: TL/DR version of my thinking: If a question or answer is worded like a Bill O'reilly or Rachel Maddow monolog, it's likely not a good format for this site.

Comment: @DA. - Asking a question with an out-of-context fact does not make it a bad question.  It just means that answers should show why that fact is irrelevant, or put it in context, etc.  Asking a question with a fact that doesn't relate to the question *does* make it a bad question.  It's the questions where the debate is over whether or not the fact relates that cause the most issues, IMHO.

Comment: @Bobson that's maybe where we disagree. If the place for a 'rebuttal' to out of context 'facts' is in the answer, then it's sounding more like a forum debate, rather than a simple Q/A--which I think is part of the issue. Some people want this to be more of a debate platform. While I *get* that, I strongly feel that SE is not the place for that.

Comment: @DA. - I think we're using different definitions for "out of context".  If I ask a question about gun control and cite a cherry-picked statistic out of its context, then the answer is *exactly* where that should be addressed.  If I ask a question about gun control and cite Mr. Talking Head's opinion on it, then that opinion should be edited out of the question (unless the question is explicitly about said opinion, of course).

Comment: @DVK - I just added [this feature suggestion](http://meta.politics.stackexchange.com/q/1515/2130) for trying to address the ideological voting issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19290/discussion-between-da-and-bobson).

Answer (score 1):

Yes!

I was really pleased to see this question:

https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/6356/which-one-is-the-more-legitimate-country-dprk-or-taiwan

was closed by 5 users, doing their jobs, without "special exception handling" from any of the mods.  Any time scare quotes are needed, it's probably a good sign the question was poor.

YAY TEAM! WAY TO GO!  THANK YOU!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Not really. This place just never has never got a solid run of active members. Some of us have come and gone. The place hasn't gotten worse, but not really better.

It's just too small of a pool of contributors to make self moderation work as well as it does on the busier sites.

Comment: Someone told me once that the various 3yr+ beta sites are basically around as a thank you to the members of the major stacks (high traffic / ad revenue) by giving them a variety of hobby stacks they can blow off steam in. I'd have to run complex [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/) queries to verify this though.

Answer (score 0):

Self-Moderation doesn't work for all users. But it depends on there experience level. I would assume users with very high rep could Self-Moderate. So its a yes and no.

Comment: I believe 'self moderation' isn't referring to individuals, but the community as a whole.